# perror segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

Code:

```
void w(char* c, int i)
{
    char * t;
    sprintf(t, "%d", i);
    perror(c);
    perror(t);
}

int main(void)
{
    w("qwe", 5);
    return 0;
}
```

causes segmentation fault, but

```
int main(void)
{
    perror("qwdasda");
    w("qwe", 5);
}
```

works. Why?
My question does not meet your quality standards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is your segmentation fault:

```
char *t;
sprintf(t,"%d",i);
```

In this code, `t` is input to `sprintf()`.  However, `t` is uninitialized so `sprintf()` will scribble on your memory.  It is almost never advisable to use `sprintf()`, use `snprintf()` instead:

```
char buf[32];
snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%d", i);
```

Answer (score 2):

The `sprintf()` call is stomping on some random memory since `t` was not initialised to point at any storage in particular.  That's probably what's crashing.